# Django - json response allowing for json[i][j] reference rather than json[0].field.field_name

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I have Django view returning JSON to JS.

```
def some_view(request, param):
    my_queryset = SomeModel.objects.filter(...).select_related('related_model')
    serialized_data = serializers.serialize( "json", [x.some_related_field for x in my_queryset])
    return HttpResponse(serialized_data, content_type='application/json')
```

Now, to get the value of some_related_field, I have to write in JS:

```
obj[i].fields.some_related_field[j]
```

My goal is to return the json from python in a way which should allow for obj[i][j] syntax. Is it possible ?

I expect I have to use dump method, but it is absolutely important that I grab the fields of a related model as well. Up to now, I've failed to grab related fields with the dump method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serialized output format depends on the serializer you're using.

If you're running Django 1.7+, you can return a [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) (with `safe=False`) instead of a `HttpResponse`. Note, you'll need to specify `safe=False` if you want to return a JSON list at the root level

e.g.

```
def some_view(request, param):
    my_queryset = SomeModel.objects.filter(...).select_related(...)
    list_data = [x.some_related_field for x in my_queryset]
    return JsonResponse(list_data, safe=False)
```

Otherwise, if you're using a version of Django less than 1.7, you could do:

```
import json

def some_view(request, param):
    my_queryset = SomeModel.objects.filter(...).select_related(...)
    list_data = [x.some_related_field for x in my_queryset]
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list_data), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Brilliant, briliiant, brilliant ! I love this site !!! Can you tell me please how can I   grab more than one field of the related model please ? Something like list_data = [x.some_related_model_id, x.some_related_model_value for x in my_queryset]

Comment: Yeah, you can do another list comprehension `[{'a': x.a, 'b': x.b} for x in my_queryset]`. However, this can get quite complicated. If you're trying to write an API, I'd suggest using a RESTful framework like Django Rest Framework

Comment: Cool, but the downside is that I have to write smth like json_obj[i].a instead of json_obj[i][j] which makes the js code less generic. No way to enable obj[i][j] syntax without REST, I guess ?

Comment: I'd recommend returning a JSON object from your API instead of a list. The reason why most APIs (and API frameworks) return a JSON object instead of a list is so metadata can be associated with the API response. e.g. pagination info, etc